# Dynamically alter drop down by the results of selecting another dynamic drop down php

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic

I am trying to *populate my second drop down by the results of the first drop down box*. I want them to be dynamic from mysql tables. This is what I have so far, the second drop down wont populate. Based on the results of selecting a `project_id`, I want to see only the tasks that are under the selected project. All help will be appreciated!!!! Yes I am aware of `mysql_query` and its vulnerabilities. I intend on going back after everything works correctly and fixing all security issues.

There are three tables involved are `projects`, `employee`, and `tasks`.

```
projects:  project_id, project_name
   tasks:  task_id, project_id
employee:  staff_id, lName, fName
```

Code as follows:

```
<?php
require_once('mainheader.php');
require_once('db_credentials.php');
?>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <div class="container">
 <h2>Please fill out all fields to register new Customers</h2>
    <form action="task_assignment_handler.php" method="post"> 
    <form class="form-vertical" role="form">

<?php

mysql_connect( $db_hostname, $db_username, $db_userpass ) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db( $db_dbname ) or die(mysql_error());

$projsql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM projects WHERE activeproject ='open'")
or die(mysql_error());

while($ProjectResults = mysql_fetch_array( $projsql ))
{
    $proj_id = $ProjectResults['project_id'];
    $proj_name = $ProjectResults['project_name'];
    $project_block .= '<OPTION value="'.$proj_id.'">'.$proj_name.'</OPTION>'; 
} 

?>
    <div>
    <label for="customer">Select a Project</label>
    <select name="task_select"><?php echo $project_block; ?></select>
    </div>




    <?php

mysql_connect( $db_hostname, $db_username, $db_userpass ) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db( $db_dbname ) or die(mysql_error());

$tasksql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE project_id=" .$proj_id)
or die(mysql_error());

while($TaskResults = mysql_fetch_array( $tasksql ))
{

    $task_id = $TaskResults['task_id'];
    $task_name = $TaskResults['taskname'];
    $task_block .= '<OPTION value="'.$task_id.'">'.$task_name.'</OPTION>'; 
} 

?>
    <div>
    <label for="customer">Select Task to assign</label>
    <select name="task_select"><?php echo $task_block; ?></select>
    </div>

<?php

    mysql_connect( $db_hostname, $db_username, $db_userpass ) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db( $db_dbname ) or die(mysql_error());

    $empsql = mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM employee")
    or die(mysql_error());

    while($empresults = mysql_fetch_array( $empsql ))

    {
    $employee_id = $empresults['staff_id'];
    $employee_fname = $empresults['fName'];
    $employee_lname = $empresults['lName'];
    $employee_block .= '<OPTION value="'.$employee_id.'">'.$employee_fname.'&nbsp'.$employee_lname.'</OPTION>'; 
    } 

?>

    <div>
    <label for="employee">Assign Employee to Task</label>
    <select name="employee_select"><?php echo $employee_block; ?></select>
    </div>










    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Assign Task</button>
    </div>


    <?php 
require_once('mainfooter.php');
?>
```

Comment: use `ajax`...http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp